# header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); returns broken image

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im fetching an blob image from my database, but it returns broken.

If i remove `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`

it returns the file extension at it should be since its a PNG file

```
‰PNG  IHDR\r¨fÆÉIDAT
```

Any ideas whats the problem ?
And yes. i tried the   `header("Content-Type: image/png");` also

I have tried with ob_start and ob_end_flush();

code

```
  ob_start();

    $query = $db->query("SELECT `image` FROM `userdetails` WHERE id = '{$_SESSION['uid']}' ");
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo $row['image'];


    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    ob_end_flush();
```

thanks

Comment: How about comparing original and fetched binary?

Comment: As you says, its a PNG, di you try `header("Content-Type: image/png");` ? Moreover, if the content is binary, may be you should add header specifying binary content (`header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");` and `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");`)

Comment: If it's a PNG, use `header("Content-Type: image/png");`. I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: @PatrickM yes sorry, I missed to write that. allready tried with the image/png

Comment: Check the output if there's anything unneccessary there, in case of such problems there's usually an error message in there somewhere.

Comment: How are you saving the image in the database? Is it in a binary safe column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask about in your question is subject to many parameters of which I fear your question does - if at all - scratch only some of them.

What pops into the eye is the PNG header:

```
‰PNG  IHDR\r¨fÆÉIDAT
```

does not look broken. So you probably did have a problem to store the image into the database. Maybe the data was truncated / modified and this change got unnoticed?

One way to deal with that is to create a checksum of the files *before* putting them into the blob to be able later on to verify the data-integrity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to output the header **before** the image data, not afterwards:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $row['image'];
```